# When creating an object, ask for all informations upfront or only necessary informations and let him complete it afterwards?

Tags: interaction-design, information-architecture

Following scenario:

I am asking the user to create a campaign and I am thinking about going for one of those two approaches:

a) Ask for everything the campaign needs to be published right in the creation process (name, description, videos, photos, location, tags, etc, takes 10+ minutes).

b) Ask for the most necessary things upfront (name, summary, target, theme) and let him create the campaign right away (takes 2 minutes). After campaign is created, I would ask him to complete/enter a few more things before he can publish it.

To me, b) seems like the more user-friendly approach since the creation process is quick and after that, he can edit and fill in the informations whenever he feels like doing or has the time to do so. In a) he needs to set 10-30 minutes aside and go through the long sign-up process.

I compare it to creating a user account (an object too). You try to ask for as little information as possible and ask him to complete his profile once he has signed up. Can I compare creating a campaign or any other object with a sign-up? What things do I have to consider?

Comment: Just allow them to enter information whenever they have it available. Only obstruct actions for which required information is still missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right to go for option (b). Once the user has committed to making the campaign they are more likely to come back and finish it. If they get half way through option (a) and stop, they lose all their work so far, and are less likely to come back to give it another go.

If you go for option (b), you may still need to give them a little nudge to get to completion. This is often done using some kind of "[gamification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)". In this instance I would suggest some kind of completeness indicator, along with nudges suggesting specifically what step to do next (with a link). [Linked-in](http://linkedin.com/) has the most well known example:

[image: Linked-in profile completeness bar examples]

Comment: As a general rule, force the user to make as few choices as possible. Choose good/sane default values as often as possible. If they want to change a setting they'll find a way to change it. Otherwise, it's just mental overhead making your product seem complicated.